# Summernote styling not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, summernote

I did a fiddle to expose the same problem I have on my desktop.

In summernote editor, applying font size and font family works, but I am unable to set font to bold, italic, strikethrough, superscript ...

My fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/by9n8azm/

Thanks for help

```
$('#my-summernote').summernote({
  minHeight: 200,
  placeholder: 'Write here ...',
  focus: false,
  airMode: false,
  fontNames: ['Roboto', 'Calibri', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial'],
  fontNamesIgnoreCheck: ['Roboto', 'Calibri'],
  dialogsInBody: true,
  dialogsFade: true,
  disableDragAndDrop: false,
  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['para', ['style', 'ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    ['misc', ['undo', 'redo', 'print', 'help', 'fullscreen']]
  ],
  popover: {
    air: [
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']]
    ]
  },
  print: {
    //'stylesheetUrl': 'url_of_stylesheet_for_printing'
  }
});
```

Same happens if I reset my code and use the one from the official demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added the following files as per the documentation (https://summernote.org/getting-started/#for-bootstrap-4). Please check.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/by9n8azm/106/

Comment: Thanks. There must be a problem with this link then : https://summernote.org/vendors/summernote/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js.